# How to cut off the filename of this url using PHP?

Tags: php

How can I transform the following link ( and many other that have the same structure) from

```
http://www.domain.com/gb/news/12/13311/here-goes-the-name-of-article.htm
```

and echo it to

```
http://www.domain.com/gb/news/12/13311/
```

I will use PHP and $_GET to get the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  use `pathinfo`

```
$path = pathinfo("http://www.domain.com/gb/news/12/13311/here-goes-the-name-of-article.htm");
var_dump($path['dirname']);
```

Output

```
string 'http://www.domain.com/gb/news/12/13311' (length=38)
```

Comment: You are welcome .. let me know if you have anymore issue ... i know how annoying down voting can be ... It not used to it myself