# How to shorten url with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have urls like this:

`http://mysite.com/launch/index.php`
`http://mysite.com/launch/index1.php`
`http://mysite.com/launch/index2.php`
`http://mysite.com/launch/index3.php`

I want to take out index.php, index1.php, index2.php, index3.php from the urls so that I would have:

`http://mysite.com/launch/`

How can I do that in .htaccess?

I want all files to load without exchanging one to another, I need just cut off the filenames from the url path.

**HINT (this may help)** - 
Only one file gets the request at a time. This file is randomly selected.
There're no other files (than index.php, index1.php, index2.php, index3.php) in the 'launch' folder.

Comment: this may help you http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html and this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @memosdp - I want all files to load without exchanging one to another, I need just cut off the filenames from the url path.

Comment: Here is the solution with php -> [how-to-cut-off-the-filename-of-this-url-using-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471108/how-to-cut-off-the-filename-of-this-url-using-php)

Comment: ohh ... with **php** as you said ... then change the title to get more help or look here http://php.net/manual/en/ to learn more about php

Comment: When you go to `http://mysite.com/launch/`, how does mod_rewrite know you want to load index.php, index1.php, index2.php, or index3.php?

Comment: @Jon Lin - Do you mean the only solution is rewriting a different keyword (folder-name) for each filename? I did it (in .htaccess), but it's not what I wanted.

Comment: Otherwise, how do you know how to route a request for `/launch`? Which one of the 4 index.php files gets handed the request? Is it random?

Comment: Yes, it's random - one file at a time.